# Repair broken double-strength glass

Tags: repair, adhesive, glass

What is the best way to glue a broken double-strength (⅛" thick) piece of glass? What sort of adhesive should I use?

The piece I need to glue back is about 6×12" in size, and it came off the edge of a ~2×3' rectangular pane.

Comment: The "best way" is to buy a new ~2x3 foot pane, or if you have something like a greenhouse with lots of them, a box-full of spares, because you will need them eventually. Glue will inevitably be substandard and problematic, IMHO, IME.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes, I was looking at adhesives, and they would cost more than buying new glass!

Comment: I assume that double strength glass (3.0 mm thick) can be cut with a glass cutter like single-strength (2.2 mm thick)?